# How long do I have to retrieve my body?

Tags: nier-automata

Based on the "Death and Recovery" tutorial, the death system seems to be similar to Dark Souls in that your body is left where you died and you will need to recover it in order to get what you lost and if you die before doing so, what was lost on that body is irrecoverable.

However, there is a secondary note about having a time limit on recovering your body before it simply disappears.

[image: death and recovery tutorial]

> When your character dies, its body remains on the map as a corpse. These bodies contain various data, so you'll have to go back to your body to retrieve your belongings.
>
> If you die again before reaching your previous body, it will disappear. **If you keep playing for an extended period of time without retrieving your body, it will disappear.**

What is the time limit?

Comment: I had a fun time dealing with some differently-coloured dudes in the Flooded City (just to prevent spoilers), and got to find about the "next time you're killed" thing in person (my Shock Wave +4 chip... ). So, this is of interest to me too. I'll look at it this evening with a blank chip.

Comment: @KBKarma yeah I lost my chips plenty of times when I was attempting a Hard playthrough. I gave that up once I ran out of chips. Never figured out how long that arbitrary time limit was, though...

Comment: To anyone wondering, I am currently trying to figure out this time limit. I've been keeping track of time on my phone's stopwatch and it's been over 2 hours now. When they said "an extended period of time," they ***really*** meant it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While I don't have the time limit for when your corpse will actually disappear, I can confirm that the time limit is longer than two and a half hours, as that's how long I waited. Two hours and 39 minutes, to be exact. Unfortunately, I had to go somewhere, which means I had to put my PS4 into sleep mode (which may or may not affect this timer, so I'd need to start the test over if I want to try again).

During my testing, I also ran to another section of the game, then fast-traveled back to near where my corpse was. The corpse was still right where I'd died, so distance and fast-traveling don't seem to affect the corpse, either.

In general, though, the purpose of my asking this question was to gauge the sense of urgency (if it existed) to get back to my corpse in time before it disappears. Apparently when the tutorial says "an extended period of time", it damn well meant it. As such, it seems like if you have any desire to recover the chips you lost when you died, there is no chance you will run out of time to do so.

If I ever have an entire day to kill, I may attempt this again to see if I can find the exact time limit. Until then, just know that the time limit is absurdly generous.

Comment: This is a complete guess but maybe progressing in the story can make your corpse dissapear? I wonder if your corpse stays when SPOILER ALERT you change character.

Comment: @fhl well, my save was erased and I haven't unlocked chapter select again yet, so I can't test that just yet. The tutorial only mentioned time, so I assumed that was the only factor in determining if/when the corpse disappeared, though

Comment: I'll test it myself tonight then.